# There is a spelling error in my comment and I can't edit it. What are my options?

Tags: support, editing

I've already made an appointment with my psychiatrist. What else can I do now that editing is no longer possible?

Comment: Delete it and re-create the comment ? it's the usual's way. (You got a 5 minutes timeout for correction)

Comment: Please see; https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/337838

Comment: In this case I happened to write two consecutive comments. I would have to delete and recreate both to preserve the sequential narrative. And if someone were to post beneath mine then it would further mess up the order.